# Aspect Oriented Programming in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, aop, goaop

I am a newbie in CakePHP and I am trying to use Go! AOP in my test application.

Eventhough I followed the guide and imported Go! by adding it to my composer.json, it seems that the AspectKernel class is not found.

```
<?php
// app/ApplicationAspectKernel.php

namespace Application;

use Go\Core\AspectKernel;
use Go\Core\AspectContainer;

/**
 * Application Aspect Kernel
 */
class ApplicationAspectKernel extends AspectKernel
{
    /**
     * Configure an AspectContainer with advisors, aspects and pointcuts
     *
     * @param AspectContainer $container
     *
     * @return void
     */
     protected function configureAop(AspectContainer $container)
    {
        $container->registerAspect(new MonitorAspect());
    }
}
```

Error: Class 'Go\Core\AspectKernel' not found
File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/app/Application/ApplicationAspectKernel.php

If there is anyone who solved this problem before, I would love to hear your opinion.

Here are my composer.json "require" values.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "ext-mcrypt": "*",
    "goaop/framework": "dev-master"
},
```

CakePHP seems to be a quite practical framework to work with and I wish I can apply AOP there to eliminate the need to put logs manually for functions' start and end (to measure the performance of the functions)

Comment: From your exlanation it sounds as if all you did was adding the entry to your `composer.json` file, not actually installing it.

Comment: Why do you need AOP to measure performance of function calls? Just use Xdebug and profile your application? Also is there really a performance problem or do you just try to optimise early? Early optimisation is the enemy of every deadline.

Comment: @ndm : I have run composer update and confirmed that the goaop/framework is in the Vendors folder, so I think I am OK with the installing.

Comment: @burzum : well, not only for measuring function calls, but also for future use like caching and checking all function calls and their parameters with ease (if we don't apply AOP, I believe we would end up having lots of line of codes just to perform that)

But my ears are all open for the function calling and parameters monitoring (call me paranoid, but I want to monitor all the activities in my app)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you place this class inside /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/app (first line comment) and is calling a namespace Application, try to use App namespace.

I got Go! working on my app.

In /webroot/index.php put this below use's statement:

```
use App\ApplicationAspectKernel;
$aspect = ApplicationAspectKernel::getInstance();
$aspect->init(array(
    'debug' => true, // use 'false' for production mode
    'cacheDir'  => dirname(__DIR__).'/tmp/aop',
    'includePaths' => [
        dirname(__DIR__) . '/src'
    ]
));
```

I've to ignore @triggers annotations in ApplicationAspectKernel inside configureAop method :

```
protected function configureAop(AspectContainer $container) {
    // use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
    AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('triggers');
    $container->registerAspect(new CacheAspect());
}
```